# Embedded Google Map - Chrome works but IE doesn't

Tags: html, google-maps, modx

I have embedded a google map into my website following link
http://index.wikidot.com/how-to-embed-a-google-map
It works well with chrome.
However, with IE when I press the zoom button, it redirects me to google maps website from my website.
I have even tried without [[embed]] in the above link.
Do I need to insert any extra index in src="" or something in order make it working?

Comment: I would assume it's an issue with IE. Which version are you using?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Can you show your example?